# Is there a way I can edit or rewrite default Matlab Apps?

Tags: image, matlab

Is there a way I can edit or rewrite default Matlab Apps such as "Image Viewer?"

Matlab R2016b

Answer (score 2):

The [Image Viewer App](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-viewer-app-overview.html) is called from the command line as [`imtool`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtool.html). You can open this file in the Editor using [`edit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/edit.html) like so:

```
edit imtool
```

or you can find its location with [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) and open it in whatever other editor you like:

```
>> which imtool
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\images\imuitools\imtool.m
```

If you really want to modify it, I suggest making a copy of your own and renaming it, leaving the built-in one unchanged and still available.

For other apps, if you go to the "APPS" tab and pull down the menu it will list all the built-in ones available:

[image]

Notice that hovering over an app will give a brief description with an associated function name in parentheses. For example, the [Video Viewer App](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/view-image-sequences-in-video-viewer-app.html) can be called with the function [`implay`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/implay.html).